# Windows Mobile 6.5 Running Program List Icon

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I've got an windows mobile 6.5 application I'm developing and am having trouble with one icon. At the top right hand of the screen there is an icon that, when clicked, will display a list of programs running the background with the option to close them.

When my program is in this list, it's icon does not show up as the others do.

I'm my exe I've got an .ico for 16x16, 22x22, 32x32, 36x36, 44x44, 45x45, 60x60, and 64x64, with the optional 90x90 png and registry setting in my cab.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but is this an HTC phone? Stock Windows Mobile does not have a "task list" icon in the system tray, so this task list is provided by the OEM. You would need to find out how they are obtaining the icon.

Chances are they are not obtaining it from the cab, but are actually getting it from your top level app window. You should check you're specifying the right icon in your WNDCLASS structure when calling RegisterClass. It is pretty common in WM to forget this because normally this icon is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Embedded Handheld (Windows Mobile) 6.5/6.5.3 Appications use the exe embedded ico files only if there is no icon via registry available. In those cases the icon also look very ugly in the start menu. So you will have to add a registry entry to an icon file.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security\Shell\StartInfo\Start\MyApp.lnk] 
"Icon"="\Windows\myapp.png"
```

See also: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2009/08/11/using-custom-icons-in-windows-mobile-6-5/